# Parquet Files in Databricks

Tags: dataframe, csv, directory, databricks, parquet

I am trying to create Parquet files in Databricks. The directory and the files exist when I check and the file path is correct. Howvwer I keep getting the message that file path does not exist for the first csv file (even though it is there!). Not sure what to do.

```
import os
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

# Define the schema for the files you want to convert
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType, DoubleType

schema = StructType([
  StructField("METER_ADDRESS", StringType(), True),
  StructField("READING_DATE", TimestampType(), True),
  StructField("READING_VALUE_L", DoubleType(), True),
  StructField("LOW_BATTERY_ALR", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("LEAK_ALR", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("MAGNETIC_TAMPER_ALR", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("METER_ERROR_ALR", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("BACK_FLOW_ALR", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("BROKEN_PIPE_ALR", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("EMPTY_PIPE_ALR", IntegerType(), True),
  StructField("SPECIFIC_ERROR_ALR", IntegerType(), True)
])

# Set the input and output directories
input_directory = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Calybre Capstone Project - Part 1"
output_directory = "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Calybre Capstone Project - Part 1/Parquet Files"

# Iterate over each file in the input directory
for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        filepath = os.path.join(input_directory, filename)

        # Read in the file using spark.read()
        df = spark.read.csv(filepath, header=True, schema=schema)

        # Write the resulting DataFrame as a parquet file
        output_path = os.path.join(output_directory, filename + ".parquet")
        df.write.parquet(output_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks, the paths should start with dbfs:/ instead of /dbfs/. So, update your input_directory variable as follows:

```
input_directory = "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Calybre Capstone Project - Part 1"
```

Your output_directory path looks okay.

Comment: Much appreciated Grimlock. I found that OS library does not work using my PC for some reason, so I've used FS instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is very inefficient way of handling multiple files - you just need to provide a file mask to list all files at the same time so they will be handled in the one go (you don't need to specify `dbfs:` or `/dbfs` when using Spark API on Databricks):

```py
input_directory = "/FileStore/tables/Calybre Capstone Project - Part 1"
output_directory = "/FileStore/tables/Calybre Capstone Project - Part 1/Parquet Files"

df = spark.read.csv(f"{input_directory}/*.csv", header=True, schema=schema)
df.write.parquet(output_directory)
```

Comment: Much appreciated Alex. I found that OS library does not work using my PC for some reason, so I've used FS instead.